# Javascript & HTML File API- can a javascript object based on a file object still contain the file's location?

Tags: javascript, fileapi

Say I have an array of user selected files.

In my application, each selected file corresponds to a person. Once the user selects the files, a table appears. In the left column is each file's name. In the right hand column, the user must fill in the name of the relevant person. Once all the names are filled in the user can upload the files. As there could be hundreds of names to fill in, I would like to be able to save the user's progress to localStorage periodically, in case the page refreshes.

I can pass each file object (var **thisFile**) to an uploading script and the browser will know where to locate the file.

However, I would like to be able to save the list of selected files in localStorage, and JSON.stringify will strip out a file object.

So say I first create a javascript object based on the file object (var **file** below).

If I then pass var **file** to the uploading script, will the browser still be able to locate the file, or would the full path to the file have been lost?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < userSelectedFiles.length; i++) {
  //File object (Stripped out by JSON.stringify).
  var thisFile = userSelectedFiles[i];
  //Create a javascript object based on the file object (Not stripped out by JSON.stringify).
  var file: {
    'lastModified': thisFile.lastModified,
    'lastModifiedDate': thisFile.lastModifiedDate,
    'name': thisFile.name,
    'size': thisFile.size,
    'type': thisFile.type
  },
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can use `onbeforeunload` event to save data before pages are unloaded. And also, you shouldn't use `JSON.stringify` on `File` objects.

Comment: @AJP please consider editing/updating your question to include the comment above in the body of the question rather than just .as comment

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I have found that a file must be reselected after a browser refresh- the location of a file cannot be stored in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can save files to offline storage.

1. Read this article about offline storage [offline_storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage) and [quota-research](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/)
2. Read documentation [LocalFileSystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem)
3. You can test offline storage here [test page](http://demo.agektmr.com/storage/)
4. How to use [link](http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html)

Here is the example for WebKit browsers (chrome and opera) of creating a file -> info.txt with your content, you need to ask a user of storage quota, in this example, is  10mb.

```
    var maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10;

    var onError = function() {};
    var requestFs = window.requestFileSystem ||
                      window.webkitRequestFileSystem ||
                      window.mozRequestFileSystem ||
                      window.msRequestFileSystem || undefined;

    var onRequest = function(grantedSize) {

      requestFs(window.PERSISTENT, grantedSize, function(filesystem) {

         filesystem.root.getFile("info.txt", {create: true}, function(DatFile) {

           DatFile.createWriter(function(DatContent) {

             var blob = /** your file or blob*/;

             DatContent.write(blob);

           });

         });

      }, onError)

    };

    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(maxSize, onRequest, onError);
```